# How to order rows in table in SQL Server in that way?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I need to order rows in my SQL Server table:

| StateID | NextStateID | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 874 | 2 | A |
| 1631 | 3 | B |
| 935 | 344 | C |
| 907 | 813 | D |
| 2 | 814 | E |
| 813 | 874 | F |
| 1 | 907 | G |
| 814 | 935 | H |
| 344 | 1631 | I |

Into the table:

| StateID | NextStateID | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 907 | G |
| 907 | 813 | D |
| 813 | 874 | F |
| 874 | 2 | A |
| 2 | 814 | E |
| 814 | 935 | H |
| 935 | 344 | C |
| 344 | 1631 | I |
| 1631 | 3 | B |

As you can see, the algorithm is as follows: starting from `StateID = 1`, you need to look at the value of the column `NextStateID` and put the row in which `StateID = NextStateID` after the previous row. And so, as long as there are such `StateID`.

Data:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
           (
               StateID int,
               NextStateID int,
               Description varchar(255)
           )

INSERT INTO @t 
VALUES (874, 2, 'A'), 
       (1631, 3, 'B'),
       (935, 344, 'C'),
       (907, 813, 'D'),
       (2, 814, 'E'),
       (813, 874, 'F'),
       (1, 907, 'G'),
       (814, 935, 'H'),
       (344, 1631, 'I')

SELECT * FROM @t
```

I would be happy to get your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a recursrve CTE

```
declare @t table(
    StateID int,
    NextStateID int,
    Description varchar(255)
    );

insert into @t values (874, 2, 'A'), 
                      (1631, 3, 'B'),
                      (935, 344, 'C'),
                      (907, 813, 'D'),
                      (2, 814, 'E'),
                      (813, 874, 'F'),
                      (1, 907, 'G'),
                      (814, 935, 'H'),
                      (344, 1631, 'I');

WITH CTE AS 
  (select 0 as level,  StateID,NextStateID,Description from @t
  WHERE StateID = 1
      UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        level +1, 
e.StateID,e.NextStateID,e.Description
    FROM 
        @t e
        INNER JOIN CTE o 
            ON o.NextStateID = e.StateID
  )
SELECT  StateID,NextStateID,Description FROM CTE
ORDER BY level
```

| StateID | NextStateID | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 907 | G |
| 907 | 813 | D |
| 813 | 874 | F |
| 874 | 2 | A |
| 2 | 814 | E |
| 814 | 935 | H |
| 935 | 344 | C |
| 344 | 1631 | I |
| 1631 | 3 | B |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qFibtJKF)